# Is a sub Markov chain also a Markov chain?

Tags: probability, markov-process, information-theory

Let us assume $A \rightarrow B \rightarrow C \rightarrow D$ is a markov chain. Can we also state that $A \rightarrow C \rightarrow D$ is also a Markov chain? It intuitively feels right. Can anyone give a formal proof of it or maybe cite some resource. It is immensely important for me.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1949897/is-any-subchain-of-markov-chain-also-a-markov-chain